# NetBeans will not launch for the first time

Tags: gnome, kde, netbeans

Hopefully someone can assist. I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and have just put the KDE Plasma desktop in place as Gnome is awful.

Everything all works fine, expect I have just installed NetBeans 8.1 using Synaptic, and when I go to launch it, it does not start.

The blue NetBeans image appears stating that it is 'initializing', but it then vanishes after about 10 seconds and closes.

Any ideas what may be occuring.

I switched back to Gnome in case the DE switch was at fault, but it does the exact same thing in Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it from shell:

```
$ /bin/sh /usr/local/netbeans-8.1/bin/netbeans
```

and you may see some error messages.